# Cassandra cqlsh report Bad request for Using Consistency

Tags: cassandra, cql

Datastax manual say that I can change consistency level with "USING CONSISTENCY" syntax.
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/cql_data_types#specifying-consistency-level

But, Cassandra cqlsh report Bad request for Using Consistency.

```
cqlsh:db_simple> show version
[cqlsh 2.3.0 | Cassandra 1.2.3 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.35.0]

cqlsh:db_simple> SELECT * FROM test WHERE a=1;

 a | b  
---+---------
 1 | example

cqlsh:db_simple> SELECT * FROM test USING CONSISTENCY ONE WHERE a=1;
Bad Request: line 1:19 missing EOF at 'USING'
```

What do I miss ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WITH CONSISTENCY LEVEL clause has been removed from CQL commands in 1.2. Programmatically, you now set the consistency level in the driver. On the command line, you can use a new cqlsh [CONSISTENCY command](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/cql/CONSISTENCY#cqlsh-consistency).

In your case you have set like

```
cqlsh:keyspace> CONSISTENCY ONE;
Consistency level set to ONE.
```